# Grab some text with regex

Tags: php, regex

Hello everyone I have some problem to grab movie title with regular expression.

how can i grab

```
<title>არ დანებდე 2 / Никогда не сдавайся 2  / Never Back Down 2</title>
```

the text between title tag with regular expressions please help me.

Comment: Do you need all of the movie title translations or just the english?

Comment: i need all the movie title between <title> tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PHP use

```
preg_match('@<title>([^<]+)</title>@', $yourTitleText, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a version for C# style regex

```
<title[^>]*>(?<Title>[^<]*)</title
```

Which language you use?

For php, akhilless is correct:

```
preg_match('@<title>([^<]+)</title>@', $yourTitleText, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

works.